# Android - Replace build in dialler screen with a Custom screen with controls

Tags: android

As per the requirement,I have to replace the android's build in dialler screen by a custom screen along with the controls. How to achieve this..???

thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download this [example](http://android.programmerguru.com/simple-dialer-application/#), and edit it how you please.

[This one](http://code.google.com/p/nubdial/) and especially [this one](https://bitbucket.org/dnaq/dialer2/overview) are even better, but may be more than what you want.

**RESPONSE TO COMMENTS**:

So you want to edit the stock dialer screen to add a button? This is not possible...though you can create a service which runs as an overlay whenever the dialer is shown which has a clickable button you can intercept. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android) for how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your kind efforts but this is not the solution I was looking for.I want to add new controls to dialler screen like : new image,new button etc.

Comment: So you want to add a button to the stock screen? This is not possible...though you can create a service which runs as an overlay whenever the dialer is shown which has a clickable button you can intercept. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android

Comment: Dats the solution.Thanx a lot for your efforts.